# Certificate paths for Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run CLI commands on new beanstalk instances when they start.

The CLI commands require env vars so I've set these in my bash script:

```
export EC2_BASE=/opt/aws
export EC2_HOME=$EC2_BASE/apitools/ec2
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=$(ls $EC2_BASE/certificates/*-pk.pem)
export EC2_CERT=$(ls $EC2_BASE/certificates/*-cert.pem)
export EC2_URL=https://ec2.amazonaws.com
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:$EC2_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
```

In the logs I see the certificate paths are not working and causing errors.

```
  ls: cannot access /opt/aws/certificates/*-pk.pem: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct path for the certificates?
I'm using the default linux ami.

The point of all this is to dynamically assign an elastic ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances don't contain `Private Key File` and `X.509 Certificate`, you must upload them by yourself.

Comment: What's the best way to do this? Should I include them in my app - or can I obtain them via the bash script?

Comment: Use Configuration File to customize EB environment or Use Custom AMI.

Comment: is including the certs in the app a bad idea?

Comment: I do not think it a good idea to use CLI in Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances.
I usually don't SSH into Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance except debuging.